# Возврат к позиции на странице при нажатии "Назад"

Tags: google-chrome, opera, firefox, кэширование, кроссбраузерность

Есть страница (каталог товаров), при прокруте вниз ajax-ом подгружаются новые товары.

Юзер щёлкает по товару, переходит на другую страницу, а там жмёт "Назад".
Браузер возвращается обратно в каталог, НО:

- Firefox ставит курсор на том месте страницы, откуда пользователь ушёл
- Chrome и Opera ставят курсор сверху.

Почему так? Как сделать, чтобы Хром и Опера вели себя подобно Мозилле?

Comment: Что есть курсор? Прокрутка страницы на нужное место?

Comment: да, именно.
мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вернулся на предыдущую страницу и не листал заново до того места, откуда ушел

Answer (score 1):

Как я недавно узнал, в Chrome не реализован ["bfcache"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218733/1026), т.е. в Firefox кнопка "Назад" (если хватило памяти) просто возвращает страницу в том виде, в котором она была в момент ухода, а в Chrome всегда перезагружает ее "с чистого листа", не сохраняя модификации, которые вы внесли через JS. Соответственно, того места страницы, откуда пользователь ушел, уже просто нет.

Ну и в Firefox это тоже не всегда работает - зависит от того, сколько у юзера памяти, не перезагружал ли он Firefox и т.п.

Правильное решение:

- При прокрутке обновлять URL страницы (`pushState` в современных браузерах, "hashbang" (http://example.org/products#!page5) в более старых - если в них вообще нужна бесконечная прокрутка).
- При загрузке в случае с pushState сервер должен уметь возвращать правильный кусок страницы по URL, а для hashbang-решения JS в onload дозагружает и отображает нужный кусок.

Вот тут подробнее про преимущества `pushState` и про то, как придумать URL для прокрутки:
http://tumbledry.org/2011/05/12/screw_hashbangs_building

PS. Не могу не вставить https://xkcd.com/1309/

[image: XKCD infinite scrolling]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сохранять X,Y курсора в файл или переменную а потом загружать ИЛИ сделайте переход при загрузке страницы вниз.